# Add a private reference to an object

Tags: c#, debugging

I need to add a private reference to a Unit object `_Unit`. Attached is both classes (`Unit` and `Result`).

I understand I need to have the code below, however it results in errors (listed below):

```
// 14. create new class
class Result : Unit
```

and the below creates the error that `base()` requires two constructors:

```
// 17. Create constructor for the class
public Result(string grade, Unit _Unit) : base(_Unit)
```

In my unit class there are two private strings `_Code` and `_Name`. Please ask if you need any other class codes put in or the assignment question.

```
namespace SIT232_Assignment1
{
  // 14. create new class
  class Result
  {
    // 15. Add a private reference to a Unit objectand a private string attributes.
    private string _Grade, _Unit;

    // 16. Encapsulate the above attributes with public read-only properties
    public string Grade
    {
        get { return _Grade; }            
    }

    // 17. Create constructor for the class
    public Result(string grade, Unit _Unit) 
    {            
        _Grade = grade;            
    }

    // 18. create a public read-only property of type bool
    public bool Passed (string grade)
    {
        bool result = true;
        if (_Grade == "N")
            result = false;
        return result;
    }

    // 19. Create a public static methods 
    public static bool ValidateGrade(string grade)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (_Grade == "N" || _Grade == "P" || _Grade == "C" || _Grade == "D" || _Grade =="HD")
            result = true;
        return result;            
    }

    // 20. Define a ToString method
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}\t{1}", _Grade);
    }
}

namespace SIT232_Assignment1
{
  // 8. Create new class
  class Unit
  {
    // 9. Add private string attributes for the unit code and unit name
    private string _Code, _Name;

    // 10. Encapsulate the above attributes with public read-only properties.
    public string Code
    {
        get { return _Code; }            
    }                
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }            
    }     

    // 11. Create constructor with two string parameters
    public Unit( string code, string name)
    {
        _Code = code;
        _Name = name;
    }

    // 27. create a private list<>
    private List<Student> _EnrolledStudents = new List<Student>();

    // 28. Encapsulate the above list with read-only
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Student> EnrolledStudents
    {
        get { return _EnrolledStudents.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    // 29. Create a method that accecpts a single parameter
    public void RecordEnrollment(Student student)
    {
        _EnrolledStudents.Add(student);
    }

    // 30. Create a method that accecpts a single parameter
    public void RemoveEnrollment(Student student)
    {
        _EnrolledStudents.Remove(student);
    }

    // 12. Define a ToString method
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1}", _Code, _Name);
    }
}
```

Furthermore, one other error I'm getting that I simply cannot full understand is the below method HAS to be *static*, I've researched that also making the attributes and properties of `_Grade` *static* solves the error showing on each individual `_Grade`, however it still shows on the first one?

```
if (_Grade == "N" || _Grade == "P" || _Grade == "C" || _Grade == "D" || _Grade =="HD")

public static bool ValidateGrade(string grade)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question:

Your class `Result` inherites from `Unit` and your constructor of `Result` calls the one of the base class. However, in `Unit` there is only one constructor defined needing two arguments (`code` and `name`), so your call to `base` at the `Result` constructor needs to have two parameters.

But you probably don't want to inherit from `Unit` but add a private reference to it. There you would have something like

```
class Result {

  private Unit _Unit;

  ...

  public Result(..., Unit _Unit)
  {
      this._Unit = _Unit;
      ...
  }
}
```

Your second error: A static method can only access static fields and properties, so from a static method you can't access your instance variables. You just want to verify that the supplied `grade` is in your range, so just don`t refer to the instance variable`_Grade`:

```
public static bool ValidateGrade(string grade)
{
  return (grade == "N" || grade == "P" ...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I opted to use Bram W's answer regarding the first problem. However, your input on the second problem fixed the error.

Comment: I understood assignment 15 (// 15. Add a private reference to a Unit object) a little bit more like hiding(boxing) it but not inheriting from it, but ok :-)

Answer (score 1):

You **Unit** class constructor expects two arguments.

When calling Base in the **Result** class you must invoke it with two arguments

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your Result class, the _Unit field has to be of type Unit, not string.
The error of the base constructor your getting is because you specified 2 parameters in the constructor of your Unit class. Either you'll have to add another constructor to the Unit class, or change the constructor of the Result class to for example

```
public Result(string grade, Unit _Unit) : base(_Unit.Code, _Unit.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention on the constructor. This is the type we're taught so best use this.